# How to get number of nested objects in object?

Tags: javascript

I have an Object. How to get number of nested objects in `a`?

```
a = {
    firstNested: {
        name: 'George'
    }
    secondNested: {
        name: 'James'
    }
}
```

I supposed to use `.length` which is usually used for arrays. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, duplicate of above.. Just use:

```
var a = {1:2, 3:4}, 
    count = 0, 
    item; 

for(item in a) {
    count++; 
}

alert(count);
```

Comment: In your example that's fine, but in the case that the object inherits some other properties...`hasOwnProperty` in the `for` loop

Comment: The best way to answer duplicate question is to not answer them.